# Getting a php variable value back with an ajax result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, croppie

I'm using croppie.js to crop user uploaded imaged, once the crop is done ajax is used to upload the result. Here is the codes for that...

Page A..

```
$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (resp) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "uploadown/uploader.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"image":resp},
            success: function (data) {
                html = '<img id="cropresult" style="margin: 0px;" src="' + resp + '" />;
                $("#uploaded-input").html(html);                
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then uploader.php is..

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['image'];
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$imageName = time().'.png';
file_put_contents($imageName, $data);
?>
```

As you can see uploader.php is using `time()` for the $imageName variable.

I either need to pass $imageName back to Page A during upload
or
set $imageName in page A first and pass it to uploader.php at the same time as the image info.

After a few hours and many attempts having read many similar questions on here and cannot work out how to do this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not `data` instead of `resp` that you have to use in the success function ?

Comment: The image upload side is working as I expect, I'm having trouble trying to grab the $imageName variable at the time it uploads to later use.

Comment: I would adjust your PHP to respond with the new File Path and Name (use `echo` or `print()`). This way your jQuery can gather this detail in the `success` callback. Right now, since you're using the original detail from Croppie, it's not pointing to the file that was uploaded.

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you want to do, do you want to pass the information of the name of the image to uploader.php from Page A?

Comment: Yes either way around would work, Set $imageName to time() in Page A then pass it to uploader.php at the same time as the cropped image blob or leave it as it is now and pass the info back to page A at the time of upload.

Comment: What prevents you from adding $imageName as a second argument in `data` in Page A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo out the `$imageName` in php file, once done use it in javascript.

PHP

```
<?php 
  $data = $_POST['image'];
  list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
  list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
  $data = base64_decode($data);
  $imageName = time().'.png';
  if(file_put_contents($imageName, $data)){
    echo $imageName;
  } else {
    echo " ";//In this case src will be empty
  }
?>
```

Java script

```
$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (resp) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "uploadown/uploader.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"image":resp},
            success: function (data) {
                html = '<img id="cropresult" style="margin: 0px;" src="' + data + '" />';
                $("#uploaded-input").html(html);                
            }
        });
    });
});
```

For any queries comment down.

Answer (score 1):

just `echo` the name in php or `var_dump()` the array and then you will be able to access it in your javascript
all the data from the php page is addign to the variable name you  give to the anonymous function you give to the success callback. for your case it will be accessed as `data`

Comment: I have tried to echo $imageName in uploader.php but then don't know how to read it back in Page A Ajax response part

Comment: i have edited the answer to explain that

Answer (score 0):

Found your full exmaple here: https://websolutionstuff.com/post/crop-image-before-upload-using-croppie-plugin

Consider the following PHP.

```
<?php 
  $data = $_POST['image'];
  list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
  list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
  $data = base64_decode($data);
  $imageName = time().'.png';
  if(file_put_contents($imageName, $data)){
    echo "Success, " . $imageName;
  } else {
    echo "Error, unable to Put file.";
  }
?>
```

This will provide a response to the AJAX Script.

```
$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
  $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
    type: 'canvas',
    size: 'viewport'
  }).then(function (resp) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "uploadown/uploader.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { "image":resp },
      success: function (data) {
        var response = data.split(",");
        var html;
        if(response[0] != "Error"){
          html = '<img id="cropresult" style="margin: 0px;" src="' + response[1].trim() + '" />';
          $("#uploaded-input").html(html);
        } else {
          console.log(data);
        }               
      }
    });
  });
});
```